# The first and the second mean-value theorems on the integral [Zorich's book]

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Show that if the function $g$ is smooth, then the second mean-value
> theorem can be reduced to the first mean-value theorem through
> integration by parts.
>
> **Theorem 1** (First mean-value theorem for the integral). *Let $f,g\in \mathcal{R}[a,b], m=\inf\limits_{[a,b]}f(x),$ and
> $M=\sup\limits_{[a,b]}f(x).$ If $g$ is nonnegative (or nonpositive) on
> $[a,b]$, then $$\int\limits_{a}^{b}(f\cdot g)(x)dx=\mu
>  \int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx,$$ where $\mu\in [m,M].$ If, in addition, it is
> known that $f\in C[a,b],$ then there exists a point $\xi\in [a,b]$
> such that $$\int\limits_{a}^{b}(f\cdot g)(x)dx=f(\xi)
>  \int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx.$$*
>
> **Theorem 2** (Second mean-value theorem for the integral). *Let $f,g\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ and $g$ is a monotonic function on $[a,b]$, then
> there exists a point $\xi\in [a,b]$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b}(f\cdot
>  g)(x)dx=g(a)\int_{a}^{\xi}f(x)dx+g(b)\int_{\xi}^{b}f(x)dx.$$*

So we are given that $g\in C^1[a,b]$ and somehow we need to show that Theorem 2 can be reduced to Theorem 1. The phrasing of the problem sounds a bit confusing to me and I am lost to be honest.

I cannot understand what does mean the phrasing *"Theorem 2 can be reduced to Theorem 1"?

So I would be very grateful if someone can explain me it and show the solution. Yesterday I spent almost the whole day trying to make some progress but eventually I gave up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$F(u) =\int_a^u f(x)dx $$

Using integration by parts and the first mean value theorem we obtain $$\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx =F(b)g(b) -\int_a^b F(x) g'(x) dx =F(b)g(b) -F(\xi) \int_a^b g'(x)dx =g(b)\int_a^b f(x)dx -(g(b)-g(a) )\int_a^{\xi } f(x)dx =g(b)\int_{\xi}^b f(x) dx +g(a)\int_a^{\xi } f(x) dx $$

Comment: Now it is clear! Thank you so much! +1

Comment: Sorry but when I started to understand some details it turned out that it is not so clear as I thought before. This is the integration by parts formula from Zorich: If the functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are $C^1$ on $[a,b]$, then $\int_{a}^{b}uv'dx=uv\mid_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}u'vdx$. So it means in order to apply integration by parts the function $F$ should be $C^1$ function on $[a,b]$. However, this is true if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Indeed, if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $F'=f$ on $[a,b]$. But we do not know is $f$ continuous or not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not necessary for $u$ and $v $to be continuously differentiable. Integration by parts works if $u$ is absolutely continuous and the function designated $v′$ is Lebesgue integrable (but not necessarily continuous). In our case $u=g, $ and $v' =f$ satisfy the assumptions.

Comment: What you wrote is actually true. But the notion of absolute continuity and Lebesgue integration is outside of this book and we can use only the integration by parts for smooth functions $u$ and $v$. So in this case we need to have the continuity of $f$, right? This is what I was asking!

Comment: Please sorry but if we use the "limited" version of integration by parts in this problem then we need to require $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$, right?